# Profile with editable edittext

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I aim with my program is to make a profile page with details that are blank for the first time use then these details can be editable and retained after clicking an update button. However, I tried many different ways like sharedprefs and firebase. It's just doesn't work to me.

The firebase way is after the update button has been clicked, it's just going to the main activity then it doesn't update or change anything.

here is the firebase code

```
showAllUserData();

        //DB
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://backend-d820a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/").getReference("user");
```

```
private void showAllUserData(){

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _NAME = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        _NUMBER = intent.getStringExtra("num");
        _ADDRESS = intent.getStringExtra("add");
        _AGE = intent.getStringExtra("age");
        _BDAY = intent.getStringExtra("bday");
        _BTYPE = intent.getStringExtra("btype");
        _COMORB = intent.getStringExtra("comorb");

        editName.setText(_NAME);
        editNum.setText(_NUMBER);
        editAdd.setText(_ADDRESS);
        editAge.setText(_AGE);
        editBday.setText(_BDAY);
        editBType.setText(_BTYPE);
        editComorb.setText(_COMORB);

    }

    public void update(View view){
        if (isNameChanged() || isNumberChanged() || isAddChanged() || isAgeChanged() ||
            isBdayChanged() || isBTypeChanged() || isComorbChanged()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data his same and cannot be updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isComorbChanged() {
        if(_COMORB.equals(editComorb.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_COMORB).child("COMORB").setValue(editComorb.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isBTypeChanged() {
        if(_BTYPE.equals(editBType.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_BTYPE).child("btype").setValue(editBType.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isBdayChanged() {
        if(_BDAY.equals(editBday.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_BDAY).child("bday").setValue(editBday.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isAgeChanged() {
        if(_AGE.equals(editAge.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_AGE).child("age").setValue(editAge.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isAddChanged() {
        if(_NUMBER.equals(editNum.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_NUMBER).child("address").setValue(editNum.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isNumberChanged() {
        if(_NUMBER.equals(editNum.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_NUMBER).child("numBER").setValue(editNum.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isNameChanged() {
        if(_NAME.equals(editName.getText().toString())){
            reference.child(_NAME).child("name").setValue(editName.getText().toString());
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Is there a simpler way to implement this?

Comment: "It just doesn't work" is really hard to help with. I recommend stepping through your code line by line in a debugger and checking the variables on each line. When you do that, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? Are there any error messages written into the logcat for that specific line?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.